# What kind of spider is this? First time I have ever seen one

Tags: species-identification, entomology, arachnology

[image: Zoomed in]

This was taken 07/06/19 in Cape Breton, NS, Canada.

I would say that it is about an inch (2.5 cm) in length and seemed to be pretty uniformly grey. The belly was the same colour as the legs, it had a few small brown spots but I couldn't tell if that was an actual marking or maybe just environmental.

It was just hanging out right beside the handle of the door exactly where you don't want a spider to be.

In usual spider fashion it has dipped and is now...somewhere :(

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have a leafcurling sac spider:

[image]

They are observed all over east and west north america:

[image]

Here is the eye arrangement from bugguide:
[image]

I labeled with arrows the two thin dots at the top, which are eyes that point upward, which are easily visible in your picture. Would need a front-facing photo to see the rest of the eyes.

The spinneretes out the back of the abdomen are also diagnostic of clubionids.
The colours can span dark yellow to light brown, and the jaws are dark and sometimes the entire front face is dark as well.

A gallery of clubionids filtered on only Canadian observations is here:
https://inaturalist.ca/taxa/121774-Clubiona/browse_photos?quality_grade=any&place_id=6712